Plain-text content incomplete when using wikivoyage API
I want to extract information about city sights and stumbled across the Wikivoyage project and their respective API.
I have the following python function which uses the query action to extract plain-text for a specific search title:
import requests

API_URL_TEMPLATE = "https://{}.wikivoyage.org/w/api.php"
USER_AGENT = "MyProject/0.0 (some-mail)" # changed for the sake of this post


def get_page_text(search_title: str, language_code: str = "de") -> str:
    params = {
        "action": "query",
        "format": "json",
        "titles": search_title,
        "prop": "extracts",
        "explaintext": True,
    }
    headers = {"User-Agent": USER_AGENT, "Accept-Encoding": "gzip"}
    response = requests.get(
        API_URL_TEMPLATE.format(language_code), headers=headers, params=params
    )
    data = response.json()
    pages = data["query"]["pages"]
    return next(iter(pages.values()))["extract"]


I tested this on a few different places and everything looked good so far. E.g. when doing:
page_text = get_page_text("Berlin", language_code="de")
I received:
("Sehenswürdigkeiten" is german for sights)
== Sehenswürdigkeiten ==


=== Highlights ===

Berlin besitzt eine sehr große Zahl verschiedener Sehenswürdigkeiten, ...


=== Kirchen und Synagogen ===

52.51895113.4005391 Berliner Dom, Am Lustgarten 1, 10178 Berlin   ​  .  · Der Berliner Dom ...
52.520613.40682 ev. Marienkirche​     ​   beim Fernsehturm. Das einzige ...

However, then I tried this for Prag there seems to be missing info:
== Sehenswürdigkeiten ==

Die wichtigsten Sehenswürdigkeiten werden hier kurz aufgezählt. Weitere Sehenswürdigkeiten sind in den Stadtteilartikeln zu finden.


=== Sakralgebäude ===


=== Burgen, Schlösser und Paläste ===


=== Bauwerke ===

When you look at the actual website you see the corresponding sights which are not shown in the plain text I got from the API call:
Screenshot of browser view, content inside read boxes is not contained in API response
What am I missing?
I thought it could maybe be a formatting thing so I played around using the 'exsectionformat' parameter (plain, wiki, raw). -> No success
Also when just retrieving the raw html with:
params = {
        "action": "query",
        "format": "json",
        "titles": search_title,
        "prop": "extracts",
}

I still see no entries.
</p>
<h2 id="Sehenswürdigkeiten"><span id="Sehensw.C3.BCrdigkeiten"></span>Sehenswürdigkeiten</h2>
<link rel="mw-deduplicated-inline-style" href="mw-data:TemplateStyles:r1626888">
<p><b>Die wichtigsten Sehenswürdigkeiten werden hier kurz aufgezählt.</b> Weitere Sehenswürdigkeiten sind in den <i>Stadtteilartikeln</i> zu finden.
</p>
<ul><li><link rel="mw-deduplicated-inline-style" href="mw-data:TemplateStyles:r1627459">
<ul><li><link rel="mw-deduplicated-inline-style" href="mw-data:TemplateStyles:r1627459"></li></ul></li></ul>
<h3 id="Sakralgebäude"><span id="Sakralgeb.C3.A4ude"></span>Sakralgebäude</h3>
<ul><li><link rel="mw-deduplicated-inline-style" href="mw-data:TemplateStyles:r1627459"></li>
<li><link rel="mw-deduplicated-inline-style" href="mw-data:TemplateStyles:r1627459"></li>
<li><link rel="mw-deduplicated-inline-style" href="mw-data:TemplateStyles:r1627459"></li>
<li><link rel="mw-deduplicated-inline-style" href="mw-data:TemplateStyles:r1627459"></li>
<li><link rel="mw-deduplicated-inline-style" href="mw-data:TemplateStyles:r1627459"></li></ul>
<h3 id="Burgen,_Schlösser_und_Paläste"><span id="Burgen.2C_Schl.C3.B6sser_und_Pal.C3.A4ste"></span>Burgen, Schlösser und Paläste</h3>
<ul><li><link rel="mw-deduplicated-inline-style" href="mw-data:TemplateStyles:r1627459"></li></ul>
<h3 id="Bauwerke">Bauwerke</h3>


